# Set Focus on QListWidget item when QStackWidget page chaged pyqt

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

maybe a trivial question, sorry in advanced but I'm definitely not an expert.

I have an UI create with Qt Designer with a `QListWidget` (5 rows) and a `QStackWidget` (5 items). I'm able to change the `QStackWidget` pages when changing one of the  `QListWidget` row with `currentRowChanged(int)` signal of `QListWidget` and `setCurrentIndex(int)` slot of `QStackedWidget`.

Is there a way to create also the same signal - slot when a page of `QStackWidget` chages so that the related row of `QListWidget` will be highligted?

I tried with signal `currentChanged(int)` and slot `setFocus()` but nothing happens.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Whats is the meaning of *when a page of QStackWidget chage*?

Comment: `stackWidget.currentChanged.connect(listWidget.setCurrentIndex)`.